# How to remote trigger parameterized jenkins jobs with R code?

Tags: r, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I remotely trigger a Jenkins job with the help of an R code?

When I post this URL in my browser it works-

```
https://JENKINSURL/job/PROJECT/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&day=20171001
```

Not sure how to replicate this with my R code. I used the POST function in HTTR call but I always get an HTTP 403 error.

```
res <- POST("https://JENKINSURL/job/PROJECT/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&day=20171001",verbose())
```

Authentication required

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
...

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked your proxy? can you explicitly give your proxy to R using `Sys` functions

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying a user ID in your request, so it is going to be using the anonymous user. Your anonymous user has to have read access to the job (or job->read in global perms) you are trying to trigger, or it won't be authorized to access the job/PROJECT uri to trigger the build.

So you have to either specify a user ID with the proper read access in the url, give the anonymous user read access, use project-based matrix auth, or you can use the *Build Token Root* plugin to provide a different URL that doesn't require read access to the job. Then you only need the token.

Comment: How would the structure of my URL look like if I provide the User ID in the request?

Comment: https ://user:apitoken@JENKINSURL/job/PROJECT/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&day=20171001  ignore the space after https. Just didn't want it to convert to a URL in the comments.

Comment: I tried the above page but it just prints a long HTML page in the console and does not trigger the job.

Comment: Try it in a browser and see what the message is. It will probably clue you into the problem.

Comment: It redirects me to the sign in page for Jenkins when I paste it in the incognito mode in browser. Maybe there is some issue with the authentication.